# Cannot read property 'charge' of undefined ... Stripe checkout with Angular and Nodejs issues

Tags: node.js, angular, http, stripe-payments

I'm integrating the Stripe checkout in my web app. I've implemented Stripe checkout on the angular front end and have also created a backend that is supposed to receive the token passed by stripe checkout. I'm getting an error of an undefined value 'charge' which is a model I created for transactions. What am I missing here to properly pass the token?

Here is the exact error I am getting. navabar.component.ts is where my checkout method is.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charge' of undefined
    at TokenCallback.token [as fn] (navbar.component.ts:104)
    at TokenCallback.trigger (checkout.js:3)
    at TokenCallback.trigger (checkout.js:3)
```

Here is my checkout method invoked by a form.

```
 openCheckout() {
    let total = (this.donation * 100);
    let handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'key_test',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (token: any) {
        const transaction = new Charge(total, token.id);
        console.log('From navbar nonObject ' + token.id + ' ' + total);
        console.log(transaction + ' From navbar');
        this.keyService.charge(transaction);
      }
    });
    handler.open({
      name: 'Delaware March for Jesus',
      description: 'Donation',
      amount: total
    });
    this.donation = 0;
    this.donationEmail = '';
  }
```

Here is my Service code that implements the charge and passes the token to the backend.

```
 charge(transaction) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(transaction);
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post(this.keysUrlDev + '/charge', body, { headers: headers })
          .map((response: Response) => response.json())
          .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

A simple angular model I constructed for transactions.

```
export class Charge {
  constructor(public amount: number,
              public token: string) {}
}
```

And my POST route on nodejs that takes the token and passes it through the stripe library charge.create method.

```
router.post('/charge', function(req, res, next) {
  var amount = req.body.amount;
  var token = req.body.token;
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Delaware March For Jesus Donation',
    source: token
  }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(req.body.amount + ' From POST' + req.body.token);
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error occured',
        error: err
      });
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Charged successfully',
      obj: charge
    });
  });
});
```

I've googled around and have tried to debug but cannot get the code to work properly. Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong?

I'd also like to note that all variables are properly defined as 'keysUrlDev' and etc. And both live and test keys are correctly placed in the checkout method on frontend and with the stripe library for the secret key on backend.

*** Error was due to this in wrong context. See answer below.

Comment: Use an arrow function `() => {}`, otherwise `this` isn't bound to what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```html
    let handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'key_test',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (token: any) {
        const transaction = new Charge(total, token.id);
        console.log('From navbar nonObject ' + token.id + ' ' + total);
        console.log(transaction + ' From navbar');
        this.keyService.charge(transaction); // The issue is here!
      }
    });
```

The problem you're running into is that you're trying to access the 'this' keyword within the wrong context.  The 'this' you are accessing in this scenario is the 'this' context of the token() function instead of the context of the component itself.  Use an arrow function instead ( () => {} ) to bind the appropriate context to the function.

Comment: Thank you. You solved the error issue along with jonrsharpe, but now I'm realizing that upon submission of the stripe checkout form, my POST http request is not hitting the backend. I'm getting no POST error or success message. Any idea why by looking at my code?

Comment: Based off your code alone, I can't see an issue.  Are you getting a response code back in your front end app for the request?

Comment: VM5900:2 Refused to frame 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/m/outer.....' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' stripecheckout: bitcoin: https://*.stripecdn.com".

I'm getting this error along with the console.logs I placed in my form checkout code, but no response or console.logs from nodejs

Comment: I also used Postman to send a post request to my API post route which responded with an error, so it works.